# Arrayformula - Gather all text from rows with same key id

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to create an arrayformula that will look at a "key id" column and gather all text from another column from all rows with the same "key id":

-- col A    /    col B    /    col C

1- KEY ID   /    NOTE     /    COMPILED NOTES

---

2- A1BZ     /    TACO     /    TACO FROG

3- T212     /    CORN     /    CORN APPLE

4- T212     /    APPLE    /    CORN APPLE

5- CD41     /    DOG      /    DOG

6- A1BZ     /    FROG     /    TACO FROG

I am using it with appsheet as a back end formula and as the sheet is active (having rows removed and added I need this to be an arrayformula. I thought some type of JOIN() with an IF statement. But I've note come up with anything that works. I can make it work if it's not an array formula with a FILTER().

Thoughts?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking here. You show three three columns of data; but what output/return do you want? What should it look like? Where should it go? (Or are you saying that you want the formula to use Col-A and Col-B data to return what you're showing in Col-C?)

Comment: By sharing spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). [Tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) are preferred. You can easily create a table using the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. However, the first row `A1:G1` must be a header row AND the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment and questions above. However, if the answer to my parenthetical question there is YES, you can delete everything in Col-C (including the header) and place the following formula in cell C1:

`=ArrayFormula({"COMPILED NOTES"; IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&"~",B2:B},"Select MAX(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1"),,9^9)),"~")),2,FALSE))})`

Comment: Sorry I was unclear as to where the formula would need to be. The arrayformula to collect  the colB note data would be in C1.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm fuzzy on the syntax for the Query, but that said it's an easy formula to follow and very adaptable. Thank you for the help

Comment: Glad it worked as you had hoped, Tom. If *learning* sheets functions is important to you, the best way to learn a thing is to take it apart, study it and put it back together. So I encourage you to do that with this formula, from the inside out if understanding is a goal.